# Dynamically setting the name label of a dynamically selected column in R data.table

Tags: r, dynamic, data.table

Is there a way to dynamically set the name of a column (or multiple columns more generally) when subsetting a data.table, selecting the original columns dynamically?

Note I am not trying to assign a new column to the original data.table in this case.

```
x <- data.table(a = 1:10, b = letters[1:10])

colname <- "b"
newcolname <- "VaR"

# The name of the column dymamically selected is an ugly 'V2'
x[a > 7, list(a, get(colvar))]
#      a V2
# 1:  8  h
# 2:  9  i
# 3: 10  j



# I want to provide the new name of the column dynamically, but don't know how to do this.  
# This clearly doesn't work, but demonstrates the spirit of what I want to achieve:
x[a > 7, list(a, (newcolname) = get(colvar))]
```

I want to achieve this, all in a data.table one liner:

```
#     a VaR
# 1:  8  h
# 2:  9  i
# 3: 10  j
```

Given two good answers, I decided to set the best answer as the fastest approach:

```
> microbenchmark(setnames(x[a > 7, .(a, .SD), .SDcols = colname], 2, newcolname)[],
+ x[a > 7, setNames(list(a, get(colname)), c("a", newcolname))])
Unit: microseconds
                                                              expr     min       lq      mean    median        uq      max neval cld
 setnames(x[a > 7, .(a, .SD), .SDcols = colname], 2, newcolname)[] 974.519 1003.993 1063.5964 1031.4020 1133.5330 1428.975   100   b
     x[a > 7, setNames(list(a, get(colname)), c("a", newcolname))] 402.693  436.531  485.8323  453.9695  493.3325 1752.296   100  a
```

Comment: I don't think this (in my opinion, silly) task needs a benchmark, but if you really want to do it, it should probably use a larger example table. Also, you should identify that speed is an important criterion to you in your initial post, not as a "winning conditions" edit.

Comment: You guys are way too serious on here.  They were both good answers.  I simply used that to choose between two good answers that were otherwise hard to pick a best from.   It's not a big deal

Comment: And for the record, roughly the same outcome happens if you extend out the data.table to many more rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set the names of the list dynamically

```
x[a > 5, setNames(list(a, get(colname)), c("a", newcolname))]
```

The `setNames()` function allows you to name the elements of your list.

Comment: Thanks.  You have a typo:  a > 7 in i of data.table

Comment: Thanks. Fixed that.

Answer (score 1):

We can try

```
 setnames(x[a > 7, .(a, .SD), .SDcols = colname], 2, newcolname)[]
```